# Angularjs search filter doesnot search in all the pages

Tags: angularjs

The search filter only finds the records from the current page. And I want it to search from all the pages. I have used $scope.watch but I guess I am lacking knowledge in that. How shall I do it? Greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

HTML:

```
<md-input-container flex>
    <label>Search Participant</label>
    <input ng-model="search" type="text" style="cursor: pointer;"/>
</md-input-container>

<div class="search-container">
    <md-table-container>            
        <form class="epForm">
            <table md-table md-row-select multiple >
                <thead md-head>
                    <tr md-row>
                    <th md-column><span><!-- <input type="checkbox"  ng-model="selectedAll" ng-click="checkAll()"/> -->Select</span>
                    </th>
                    <th md-column><span>Endpoint Name</span></th>
                    <th md-column><span>Endpoint Aliase</span></th>
                    <th md-column><span>Endpoint Protocol</span></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody md-body>
                    <tr md-row ng-click="" md-select-id="name" ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize |  limitTo:pageSize | filter: search ">
                        <td md-cell><input type="checkbox" ng-model="endpoint.Selected" ng-change="endpointsSelected(endpoint)"/></td>
                        <td md-cell>{{endpoint.partName}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{endpoint.partSignalId}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{endpoint.partSignalType}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <button ng-disabled="currentPage == 0" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage-1" 
                        style="background: transparent;border: aliceblue;">
                        <img src="./images/previous.jpg"/>
                        </button>
                        {{currentPage+1}}/{{numberOfPages()}}
                        <button ng-disabled="currentPage >= endpoints.length/pageSize - 1" ng-click="currentPage=currentPage+1" 
                        style="background: transparent;border: aliceblue;">
                        <img src="./images/next.jpg"/>
                        </button>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </form>
    </md-table-container>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$scope.currentPage = 0;
$scope.pageSize = 10;

$scope.$watch('search', function (v) {
    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.numberOfPages();
    //$scope.pages = $scope.range();
}, true);

LoadingShow();
PinnacaService.getEndpointList(
    $rootScope.admin.session_key,
    $rootScope.room,
    function(data, status){
        $scope.endpoints = data;
        $scope.numberOfPages=function(){
            return Math.ceil($scope.endpoints.length/$scope.pageSize);                
        }
        LoadingHide();                
    },
    function(data, status){
        if(status == 403){ //session timeout
            alert($scope.$parent.lang.session_timeout);
            $scope.$parent.logout();
        }
        $scope.msg_error = true;
        $scope.msg_error_status = status;
        $scope.msg_error_text = data;
        LoadingHide();
    });


myApp.filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
    start = +start; //parse to int
    return input.slice(start);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify following code

```
<tr md-row ng-click="" md-select-id="name" ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize |  limitTo:pageSize | filter: search ">
```

With

```
<tr md-row ng-click="" md-select-id="name" ng-repeat="endpoint in endpoints | filter: search | startFrom:currentPage*pageSize | limitTo:pageSize ">
```